# How can Jackson Deserializer recursively deserialize fields taking @JsonFormat annotations into account?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, date-formatting

In a custom Deserializer for an Entity I want to call the deserialization of (some of) the fields recursively in a way, that @JsonFormat annotations are respected. More concretely this is how the Deserializer looks like:

```
public class DealPatchDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<DealPatch> {
    public DealPatch deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode root = p.readValueAsTree();
        JsonNode redeemableFromNode = root.path("redeemableFrom");
        JsonParser redeemableFromParser = redeemableFromNode.traverse(p.getCodec());
        Date date = redeemableFromParser.readValueAs(Date.class);
}
```

In that example the JsonParser.readValueAs() does not take the annotated

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
private Date redeemableTo;
```

pattern into account, and thus generates an exception because of the unknown (German) date format.

Is there any way to deserialize fields of an object so that it respects the annotated formats?

Answer (score 0):

If the entire `redeemableFrom` object does not need custom deserialization, you can parse it as a regular Java object, with the annotations, by calling `treeToValue()`. Something like this should work:

```
p.getCodec().treeToValue(redeemableFromNode, RedeemableFrom.class);
```

Comment: Nope. The @JsonFormat is not used and as a consequence there is a HttpMessageNotReadableException because the value cannot be deserialized to a Date. My point is: I have a field that has a format annotation, how can I call this field to be deserialized so that the specified format is used?